# Redirecting dir output to my executable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wrote a simple command line c program and made its executable.
It should take file name as input and do some operations on the file.

My task is to take the input from `dir /s /b *.c` command and redirect it to my executable `Link.exe`.

I am trying it this way:

```
dir /s /b *.c | Link.exe
```

But it does not works that way.

The only way it works in if we give the file name on the right side of Link.exe file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write Linke.exe so that it takes input from stdin.  Eg in a C++ program would something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s;
    while(std::cin >> s)
      std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Link.exe can take a filename as a parameter, you could run the `dir` command through a `for` loop and use the for variable as the parameter for Link.exe

```
for /f %%A in ('dir /b /s *.c') do Link.exe "%%A"
```

Note that if you're running this on the command line instead of from a batch file, you need to replace `%%A` with `%A`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, In the solution given by you, it feeds the Input to the Link.exe every time a new file is detected. This is fine, However if you could suggest me a way to feed the output of dir for all the files at a time in Link.exe. Because Link.exe should perform action on all the input in a single session.

Answer (score -1):

You should change it to

```
dir /s /b */c > Link.exe
```

Note in Windows, it should be angular (greater than) symbol to stream output to another program.

To test this, you can run sample test like

```
dir > abc.txt
```

The output of above statement will result into list of files present in current directory getting appended in abc.txt.

Comment: In this way it writes the output of dir into my exe file and My executable gets changed .

Comment: It looks to me like he wants to pipe the output to a program - piping.

Comment: In both Windows and Unix, `|` is used to direct output from a program into the input for another program, while `>` and `>>` are used to redirect program output into a _text file_.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see that carefully.